# Ways to use php includes with absolute paths?

Tags: php

I'm trying to use absolute paths for php includes.

Right now I'm trying to do it like this:

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/sitefolder/apis/db.php');
```

but it doesn't work since my site is not pointing to the root folder so I need to add a /sitefolder.

Is there a way to bypass this producing an absolute URL? Or is there a way to permit absolute URLs including?

Comment: Use like this: `../sitefolder/` (each `.` to go up in folder but the first doesn't count. So `..` go up 1 folder, `...` 2 folders, etc...

Comment: Uh, it is `../..` to go up two folders.

Comment: don't say url... that's for http requests and the like. you're talking about an absolute **PATH**.

Comment: In path strings, `.` is the filename referring to the current directory, and `..` is the filename for the parent directory. Anything else (such as `...`) does not hold any special meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a initialize.php.

And define your site root.

Include your includes file such as config.php, db.php.

And only include initialize.php to your files.

```
defined('DS') ? null : define('DS', '/');

defined('SITE_ROOT') ? null : define('SITE_ROOT',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
defined('LIB_PATH') ? null  : define('LIB_PATH', SITE_ROOT.DS.'includes');

require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'functions.php');
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'session.php');
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'database.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

i tend to use below technique to include files .

```
   include rtrim(dirname(__FILE__), '/\\') . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'my_file.php' ;
```

If its in the same dir, or relative to the same dir, you can use something like 
( **i have excluded  rtrim  function for the sake of simplicity** )

```
include dirname(__FILE__) . '/file.php';
include realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../dir') . '/file.php';
include realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../dir/file.php');
```

defining constant also do great job .

```
define('BASEDIR', dirname(__FILE__));
define('LIBDIR', BASEDIR . '/lib');
```